# Android Studio not working ( gradle resolve dependencies app _debugcompile )

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

From yesterday Android Studio new project not working (or hang) .
gradle resolve dependencies app _debugcompile stop and not working.

Image problem :
[image: gradle resolve dependencies app _debugcompile]

[image: gradle]

Comment: it's just 3 minutes since build started. It usually take more than 5 minutes for first run

Comment: install any new updates require . It is happened with me also after installation new updates every thing working smooth for me .

Comment: i wait 30 min But nothing happened . update everything

Comment: then it must be downloading something

Comment: Yes, but computer connected to the Internet

Comment: yes but downloading dependencies can take time if your internet speed is slow and use too much dependencies

Comment: where is your app gradle file??

Answer (score 0):

Can you show use the gradle file?

Maybe there is a problem  with it. Do you try when it failed  to resynchronise your project  with the gradle  button?

Comment: I can't  comment the first answer =).